# scanf and the p conversion specifier

Tags: c, c11, format-specifiers

In the C11 specification is said that argument type of `%p` must be `void **` in case of `scanf()` function but I can't figure how to input an address and store it into a `void **`.
Infact if I try to make:

```
void **p;
scanf("%p", p);
```

I get a segmentation fault.

P.S.
C11 specification:

> The corresponding argument shall be a pointer to a pointer to void

Comment: I don't get what is the actual use-case of this `scanf()` Hard-coding a address for what purpose? do you have MC where you know the actual locations to which you need to scan the values to?`p` is a double pointer and it should be made to point to a pointer which we don't see in the code shown.

Comment: @Gopi, Yes I know and in fact I don't understand why the standard says to use a double pointer!

Comment: I request you not to _change_ your question in a way so that the previously submitted answers look wrong. Consider adding the extra information _keeping_ the original post unchanged. Aslo, when asking question realted to a _specific standard_, kindly use the appropriate tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>**NOTE: Original post did not have a mention for `c11` standard.**</sup>

Well, as per the `c99` specification document, chapter 7.19.6. <strike>1</strike> 2, paragraph   <strike>8</strike>  12,

> p
>
> Matches an implementation-defined set of sequences, which should be the
>   same as the set of sequences that may be produced by the %p conversion of
>   the fprintf function. The corresponding argument shall be a pointer to a
>   pointer to void. The input item is converted to a pointer value in an
>   implementation-defined manner. If the input item is a value converted earlier
>   during the same program execution, the pointer that results shall compare
>   equal to that value; otherwise the behavior of the %p conversion is undefined.

<strike>So, it is not `void **`, rather , a `void *`.</strike>

<strike>Next,</strike> Your reason for a segmentation fault is the use of uninitialized pointer `p` in `scanf()`. You did not allocate memory to `p` before using [passing it to `scanf()` as argument] it.

As others' suggested, you can nicely use something like

```
void *p;
scanf("%p", &p);
```

here, the `&p` value is actually `pointer to a pointer to void` and have a defined address.

Comment: Into C11 specification is said: "The corresponding argument shall be a pointer to a pointer to void"

Comment: @xdevel2000 well, the reason of segmentation fault is use of uninitialized pointer.

Comment: 7.19.6.1 is `fprintf`, not `fscanf`.

Comment: @mafso A big thanks. Really really I should have been careful. Updated answer with correction.

Comment: What would `%p` even be used for?

Answer (score 6):

```
void **p;
scanf("%p", p);
```

doesn't work for the same reason that

```
int *i;
scanf("%i", i);
```

doesn't work - you're writing to an uninitialized pointer (or telling `scanf` to write to one, at least).

This works:

```
int i;
scanf("%i", &i);
```

and so does this:

```
void *p;
scanf("%p", &p);
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't initialize `p`. Try:

```
void *p;
scanf("%p", &p);
```

This takes the address of `p`, which is valid.

Answer (score 0):

Standard says that `%p` should have `void *` type argument.  You need to declare `p` as `void *` and then

```
scanf("%p", &p);
```

The reason that you are getting segfault is because in `void **p`, `p` is not pointing anywhere.